# I getting CIDR error while doing terragrunt apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group, terragrunt

main.tf inside modules/sg

```
  //vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  //all inbound traffic
  ingress {
    from_port   = "22" //opens tcp 22 port for ssh
    to_port     = "22"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [var.trusted_ip_ingress]
  }
}
```

variable.tf inside modules/sg

```
variable "trusted_ip_ingress" {}
```

terragrunt.hcl

```
  source = "./../../../modules//sg"
}

inputs = {
  trusted_ip_ingress = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

Please find the error while doing terragrunt plan
[error message while doing terragrunt plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7A6n.png)

Comment: How did it go? I see you asked new question, without accepting my answer to your old question, or even explain why it is not satisfactory?

Answer (score 1):

Your `trusted_ip_ingress` is already a list. So you should use:

```
  ingress {
    from_port   = "22" //opens tcp 22 port for ssh
    to_port     = "22"
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks =  var.trusted_ip_ingress
  }
```